# Kronecker product vec trick but middle matrix is transposed

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

There are famous Kronecker product trick
$$
vec(AXB) = (B^T \otimes A)vec(X)
$$
where $vec(X)$ - stacks columns of $X$. It's super useful when we need to take derivatives of expression with respect to vectorized version of $X$

I have a little bit different situation, i need to find such matrix $M$ for which
$$
y = vec(X^TB) = Mvec(X)
$$
I can use Kronecker product trick to obtain
$$
y = vec(IX^TB) = (B^T\otimes I)vec(X^T)
$$
But there are still $X^T$. Can anyone explain how i can get rid of transpose? I'm pretty sure it's possible to use row major $vec$ but problem is - my whole computations built around column major $vec$, so it's quite problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a potential solution. Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ entry and $0$ elsewhere. Then define
$$
U = \sum_{ij} E_{ij} \otimes E_{ji}.
$$
Note that $U$ is a unitary matrix. In quantum information it is referred to as the swap operator because it has the follow property
$$
U (e_i \otimes e_j) = (e_j \otimes e_i)
$$
where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. As Ben Grossmann notes, it also goes under the name commutation operator.

Writing $X = \sum_{ij} x_{ij} E_{ij}$ we find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{vec}(X^T) &= \mathrm{vec}(\sum_{ij} x_{ij} E_{ji}) \\
&= \sum_{ij}x_{ij} e_{j} \otimes e_{i} \\
&= U \sum_{ij} x_{ij} e_{i} \otimes e_{j} \\
&= U \mathrm{vec}(\sum_{ij} x_{ij} E_{ij}) \\
&= U \mathrm{vec}(X)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus you have
$$
y = (B^T \otimes I) U \mathrm{vec}(X).
$$

Comment: The matrix $U$ is sometimes called a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, good to know!