# Closed form solution to matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following matrix equation for $L$:

$$A\cdot L + L^T = 0$$
where A is non-singular and both $A,L \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I'm wondering if this could have a closed-form solution.

This seems close to Sylvester's equation but not quite the same.

Comment: What do you mean by having a closed-form solution? Like a reasonable parametrization? This equation has probably not only one solution, right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It doesn't seem to have a unique solution so a parameterization would be good.

Answer (score 2):

I begin by three examples showing that the solutions of

$$AL+L^T=0\tag{1}$$

can depend on parameters.

a) If we take

$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&-1},$$

then the general solution of (1) is :

$$L=\pmatrix{0&a&0\\-a&b&-2b\\0&-2b&4b},$$

with $\det(L)=4a^2b$.

b) If $$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1}$$ (in fact it is a commutation matrix that will be used later on), the general solution depends on 4 parameters :

$$L=\pmatrix{0&a&a&c\\-a&b&-b&d\\-a&-b&b&d\\-c&-d&-d&0}$$

with $\det(L)=0.$

c) For the $6 \times 6$ matrix :

$$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0}$$

the general solution depends on $9 $ (!) parameters :

$$L=\pmatrix{0&e&b&a&b&e\\
-e&i&-f&-g&-h&-i\\
-b&h&d&-c&-d&f\\
-a&g&c&0&c&g\\
-b&f&-d&-c&d&h\\
-e&-i&-h&-g&-f&i}$$

with the interesting factorization of

$$\det(L)=(2ce - 2bg + af + ah)^2(2fh  + 4di - f^2 - h^2)$$

Please note that in the three examples, the solutions are the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix (see the connection with the answer by @user1551).

---

How such solutions can be obtained ? By the following method :

Begin by "vectorizing" relationship (1) :

$$vec(AL)+vec(L^T)=vec(0)\tag{2}$$

(vectorization of a $n \times n$ matrix means : "stacking its columns into a $n^2 \times 1$ vector").

Based on classical relationship $vec(AXB)=(B^T \otimes A) vec(X)$ where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product, (2) can be written under the form :

$$(I_n \otimes A) . vec(L) + U . vec(L) = vec(0),\tag{3}$$

where $C$ is the ($n^2 \times n^2$) commutation matrix : see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185147/305862).

$$\underbrace{(I_n \otimes A+C)}_D . vec(L) = vec(0),$$

Otherwise said, $vec(L)$ is any vector of the *kernel* of $$D:=I_n \otimes A + C,$$

with possible dimensions $0,1,2 ...$  (even more than $n$) in the examples given  above, the dimensions are $2$ and $4$ resp.). The dimension of the kernel can be

This gives you a way to obtain a general form for $L$ using software tools where Kronecker product is implemented (see general Matlab program below).

Remark : Writing the initial relationship under the form

$$AL=-L^T,$$

and taking the determinant on both sides, one sees that either $\det(L)=0$ or, if $\det(L) \ne 0$, a necessary condition on $A$ for having solutions to (1) is : $\det(A)=(-1)^n$.

Here is a (Matlab) program with the matrix of the first example, but which can be used for any matrix :

```
 A=[1,0,0;
    0,1,1
    0,0,-1];
 n=size(A,1);
 I=eye(n); % identity matrix n x n
 % creation of the commutation matrix C at order n :
 Col=[];
 for p=1:n;Col=[Col,p+n*(0:n-1)];end;
 I2=eye(n^2);C=I2(:,Col); 
 D=kron(I,A)+C;
 Kb=null(D,'rational'); % basis of the kernel in a n x d array
 d=size(Kb,2);
 disp('kernel dimension : '),d
 if d>0
    disp('the gen. sol. is a linear combination of :')
    for k=1:d;reshape(Kb(:,k),n,n);end;
 else disp('therefore no non trivial solution')
 end;
```

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge of commutation matrices. So, U is a class of matrices and that's how the final solution can have infinite solutions. Also, what does the kernel of the summation above mean?

Comment: Commutation matrix $U$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix)) is not a class of matrices but a unique matrix with $0,1$ entries, About the kernel of matrix $V:=I_n \otimes A + U$, it is the set of vectors $n^2 \times 1$ $X$ such that $VX=0$. I am going to re-write some sentences of my answer.

Comment: Did you know Kronecker product beforehand ?

Comment: If you desire to know many properties of commutation matrices, see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-7/issue-2/The-Commutation-Matrix-Some-Properties-and-Applications/10.1214/aos/1176344621.full).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jean! I didn't know about the Kronecker product but I checked on that.

Comment: Is there a way to interpret the solutions of the kernel for D in terms of A e.g. its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: You mean the kernel of $I \otimes A + D$ ? With my method, I don't know : I don't see in particular how to relate it to the method given by user1551 (when $A$ is diagonalizable.)

Comment: I have modified my answer : 1) I have given a third example having a solution with many parameters 2) I have corrected a false remark (that the dimension of the kernel couldn't exceed $n$) 3) Besides, I see in a better way the connection with the answer by user1551.

Answer (score 2):

Here we give an explicit general solution when $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. In this case, $A$ possesses a [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), i.e., $A=M\Lambda M^{-1}$ for some real invertible matrix $M$ and real block-diagonal matrix
$$
\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_k)
$$
where $B_i$ and $B_j$ have not any common complex eigenvalue whenever $i\ne j$, and
$$
B_i=r_iI\ \text{ or }\ B_i=|r_i|\operatorname{diag}(R_{\theta_i},R_{\theta_i},\ldots,R_{\theta_i}),\tag{0}
$$
for some real number $r_i$ and for some $2\times 2$ rotation matrix $R_{\theta_i}$ for an angle $0<\theta_i<\pi$. Let $X=M^{-1}L(M^{-1})^T$. The equation $AL=-L^T$ then becomes $\Lambda X=-X^T$.

Partition $X$ as a $k\times k$ block matrix, so that its $i$-th diagonal sub-block has the same size as $B_i$. Denote the $(i,j)$-th sub-block of $X$ by $X^{ij}$. The equation $\Lambda X=-X^T$ thus means that $B_iX^{ij}=(-X^{ji})^T$ for all $(i,j)$, i.e.,
$$
X^{ji}=(-B_iX^{ij})^T\tag{1}
$$
for every pair of indices $i$ and $j$. By interchanging the two indices, we also have
$$
X^{ij}=(-B_jX^{ji})^T.\tag{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
X^{ij}=(-B_jX^{ji})^T
=-(X^{ji})^TB_j^T
=-(-B_i X^{ij})B_j^T
=B_iX^{ij}B_j^T.
$$
It follows that $X^{ij}=0$ whenever $I-B_j\otimes B_i$ is nonsingular, i.e., whenever $\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}\ne1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $B_i$ and every eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ of $B_j$.

Now suppose that $i<j$ and $\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}=1$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $B_i$ and some eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ of $B_j$. There are only two possibilities:

- $(B_i,B_j)=(rI,\frac{1}{r}I)$ for some $r\not\in\{0,1,-1\}$. In this case, $(1)$ and $(2)$ become two equivalent conditions $X^{ji}=(-rX^{ij})^T$ and $X^{ij}=(-\frac{1}{r}X^{ji})^T$. Therefore one may assign an arbitrary value to $X^{ij}$ and set $X^{ji}=(-rX^{ij})^T$.
- $B_i=|r|\operatorname{diag}(R_{\theta},R_{\theta},\ldots,R_{\theta})$ and $B_j=\frac{1}{|r|}\operatorname{diag}(R_{\theta},R_{\theta},\ldots,R_{\theta})$. In this case, we have $B_j^T=\frac{1}{|r|^2}B_j^{-1}$. Therefore from $(2)$ we obtain $X^{ij}=(-B_jX^{ji})^T=-(X^{ji})^TB_j^T=-\frac{1}{|r|^2}(X^{ji})^TB_j^{-1}$, i.e., $|r|^2X^{ij}B_j=(-X^{ji})^T$. From $(1)$, however, we also obtain $(-X^{ji})^T=B_iX^{ij}$. Therefore $(1)$ and $(2)$ are consistent if and only if
  $$
  |r|^2X^{ij}B_j=B_iX^{ij}.\tag{3}
  $$
  Now partition $X^{ij}$ into sub-blocks of size $2\times2$. For each sub-block $Y$ of $X^{ij}$, $(3)$ gives $|r|^2Y\left(\frac{1}{|r|}R_{\theta}\right)=|r|R_{\theta}Y$. That is, $YR_{\theta}=R_{\theta}Y$. Hence each sub-block of $X^{ij}$ is an arbitrary scalar multiple of some rotation matrix (a.k.a. a rotation-dilation) and $X^{ji}$ is given by $(1)$.

Next, suppose that $i=j$ and $\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_j}=1$ for some two eigenvalues $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ of $B_i$. Since $B_i$ is in the form of $(0)$, we must have $B_i=\pm I$ or $\operatorname{diag}(R_{\theta},R_{\theta},\ldots,R_{\theta})$ for some $\theta\in(0,\pi)$:

- If $B_i=I$, $(1)$ means $X^{ii}$ is an arbitrary skew-symmetric matrix.
- If $B_i=-I$, $(1)$ means $X^{ii}$ is an arbitrary symmetric matrix.
- If $B_i=\operatorname{diag}(R_{\theta},R_{\theta},\ldots,R_{\theta})$, partition $X^{ii}$ into sub-blocks of size $2\times2$. By a similar argument to a previous one, we see that each sub-block $Y$ in $X^{ii}$ must commute with $R_{\theta}$, i.e., it is a rotation-dilation. The strictly block-lower triangular part of $X^{ii}$ is completely determined by the strictly block-upper triangular part with $(1)$. That is, if $Y$ is a sub-block in the strictly upper triangular part, then the sub-block at the symmetric position is $-Y^TR_{\theta}^T$ (which is also equal to $-R_{\theta}^TY^T$ because $R_{\theta}$ and $Y$ commute). For each diagonal sub-block of $X^{ii}$, let it be $W=cR_{\phi}$. Condition $(1)$ gives $W=(-R_{\theta}W)^T$, i.e., $R_{\theta}W=-W^T$. Hence $\theta+\phi=m\pi-\phi$ for some odd integer $m$. This means $\phi=(m\pi-\theta)/2$ and $R_\phi=\pm R_{(\pi-\theta)/2}$. By absorbing the sign into $c$, we see that $W=cR_{(\pi-\theta)/2}$ for some real number $c$.

Comment: I have often appreciated your solutions, but here I am a little lost. In order to understand your method in the case of my second example, which is a diagonizable matrix whose Jordan form is plainly $diag(-1,1,1,1)$, 
how can I retrieve with your method the general solution I give (depending on 4 parameters)

Comment: @JeanMarie When $A=M\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)M^{-1}$, we have $L=M\pmatrix{s\\ &K}M^T$ where $s$ is any real number and $K$ is any skew-symmetric $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's much clearer now !

Comment: In general, A needn't be diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: @supernova No, it needn’t.

Comment: I have added a third example in my answer, with an interesting factorization of the determinant of the general solution. Can this factorization be explained with your method ? ... Maybe by considering a Pfaffian ?

Comment: @JeanMarie In your third example the matrix is similar to, by reindexing its rows and columns, $I_2\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. In turn, it is similar to $I_4\oplus-I_2$. Hence the solutions are given by $L=M\pmatrix{K_{4\times4}\\ &S_{2\times2}}M^T$ for some invertible matrix $M$, skew-symmetric Matrix $K$ and symmetric matrix $S$. The determinant of $L$ is therefore in the form $p^2q$ where $p$, a degree-$2$ polynomial, is the Pfaffian of $K$ and $q$, also a degree-$2$ polynomial, is the determinant of $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much @user1551

Answer (score 1):

This is the Sylvester-Transpose matrix equation sometimes called the T-Sylvester equation, analyzed in [The solution of the equation $AX + X^* B = 0$](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379513X00035/1-s2.0-S0024379512008191/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCikgP4hFYUVVFP1BeFZKoo23xuQ1kwmiTPuuYgfjUrwQIgZLLenLl0iUNnYCiwkHE14Y9nBgrA408I9OokpDSzJfwquwUIgf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDIzuK6k8Q%2F6btmds2CqPBamRquD5iV%2BsOkBkJidhPxEjBESxLAMJdhAPMIqFNb1bvlrECqze%2FBOLI4xA7CO77HPJw%2FCBPNA5UOWAUV%2BKCh%2FWlM%2FHuFsDNWKA1ly7J2afd7yLlraF940Z%2B8cl5vFM80j6WQ6Xax%2Fi1KP46egX8gdnLMhgx%2FwguzQKRgPFnSt%2BNSpboygV6xpqYiSBw6v0Gi%2FT7P1QZgeDoxs5Z43Sf5R1Xh%2ByyYXSJRFmtmRDlzUNjQlNIA5Uy5DyAq6xFQ1%2BRlJaskswvVZXn71qppZanV7I7MG8vwaDQJReFfVMjZwTQ818qlR6ujG3bZU0%2F4TZxhZoIAsysS6RiIyjT9M6zoIwGN0ckF0Hae3H5%2FfOPHsHaOU9Z97yo9ICIkUKa2obTgOjp3GruGsIsnXqbaNNcYSnL76np%2BUuSMKH3PWwiQrLBXscYtSJG3w6Gt34IaxHv3Rhy8mtvnmUIsCqU8nJVRfJU3C14H3fVp2sVrCW2EHLf375F6KDg0IR8XLa1Vu3iwFgueUoGWV5C9Smp9OFPuXUpm2bDFIj1mYhtt8m%2B9xuRbnMpPdaHd6mTB0ZOkkm%2BBN1NCnvjFI2IERTo6IWAMU5wQO7iJHItjDPfbRGJMkmi84HmoF7Cu20sYRb6gJUUIVPCV3KcM7dIDBRDH3CzA7Xt%2FUrFP1TDXsU1udMVFyw1znOJrt9A%2FsL2TvgBKfhcQNQV%2BZrwbsGDBwboYtRS5LYhiZJmgnbc3JLrNbpmvfpP%2B%2F61V%2B2vBEIfOlxSK4%2FhMZ4sctru7FZh0R4n11yIpgFarcR7vIxAj3TJNxKt3jHFKeRNS3byso7kVQHbW%2FDNZ0BLfj1ngfIvnVzO1otZXbAio3drXHXuFn7aL9%2BeBUwvOTkrgY6sQHNgLKjxVcdRe2fhpdejpn0MHEwxQMb6tz8AVVLRcucgCVL%2FyHgRQe%2BaPXXYpN4Yz1fkBoPHYO4vXpYs6bk%2Fk3QhP%2FYIcz%2BtH3ZMaBur91GcenSvdE6HS9%2BmbpqgVCXb%2Bx62E1LsKaqKnZHfKBmRe2sle6bbe6FYOWvqgTrIIS%2BjZnY5PXq8kWXRdV9PWH775oaxrthVzerdwAvr4QudAJ6AiMrRz6%2FB5nhc4hW37nlqQY%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240224T002305Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQCU7SFGE%2F20240224%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ce7a5ae53c55da059a3f36d1f46cadf84c0e31a84808448cfb3659ecc40d2bd9&hash=44416ed37dcd7836b4814447279942b087af8091d8620c0861091d2fde9d83b6&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0024379512008191&tid=spdf-c7494f2c-dab5-44be-a2ff-aa0910fa5f40&sid=7408cce433aaf04228385dd4925fb754d8d2gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=15115c5b00535e0203&rr=85a38ece49ed15b0&cc=us) by Teran,Dopico

If you want to implement a solver yourself, an easier approach is to reduce it to continuous Lyapunov equation, derivation is on mathematica.SE [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207044/217).

There may be an infinite number of solutions to the continuous Lyapunov equation, but if we restrict attention to the least-squares solution, it has an elegant closed form solution in terms of eigenvectors of $A$, proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808422/998) by `user1551`